# Python decorator function call depth, structured output

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I am printing inputs and outputs of functions, but this results in hard to read logs, especially with too many nested function calls (not recursive).

**Example:**

```
Calling test1()
Calling test2()
Calling test3()
Calling test4()
'test4' returned None
'test3' returned None
'test2' returned None
'test1' returned None
```

**I would like to see the output like this:**

```
Calling test1()
    Calling test2()
        Calling test3()
            Calling test4()
            'test4' returned None
        'test3' returned None
    'test2' returned None
'test1' returned None
```

If I could keep a call count and transfer it to next calls by incrementing it each time, I could achieve this. Then I could even color the output based on the value of this count and generate easier to read logs.

Is there a way I could keep the depth of current call inside the iterator?

**For reference, here is the decorator:**

```
def trace(func):
    """Print the function signature and return value"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_debug(*args, **kwargs):
        args_repr = [repr(a) for a in args]                      # 1
        kwargs_repr = [f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]  # 2
        signature = ", ".join(args_repr + kwargs_repr)           # 3
        print(start + f"Calling {func.__name__}({signature})" + end)
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{func.__name__!r} returned {value!r}")           # 4
        return value
    return wrapper_debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python knows your call depth, anytime.

You can also print the traceback of where your currently are, anytime.

No need to keep it in a separate variable.

So here you go:

```
import traceback
len(traceback.format_stack())
```

Up to you to make the indent and to fix any off-by one errors.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed all ocurrences of decorator file from the stack and took its length so that future nested decorators or the decorator itself does not increment length.